# Batch Export in Geomedia Tiff->Geotiff

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, batch, geomedia

**GIS**: Geomedia 2015, Q-Gis 2.14

**Avaible Data**: Raster files (tif) with a seperate saved georeference in Geomedia mdb, Shapefiles with the outline of every tif file.

I'm using Geomedia 2015 and have more than 50k small Tiff files to export.
There is an option to do this in Geomedia, but only for one image at once.

I know the Coordinate System/Datum and also the 4 node coordinates for every tiff.

So, does anybody know a way to batch that process, either in Geomedia or with QGIS?